# Javascript : Changing permanently the style of an element

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I'm a beginner in web development and I probably ask something really easy.

I have a web page with a javascript clock that update himself automatically every second (self.updateDom()).

I want to change his style thanks to JavaScript (the user can customize his clock whenever he want). 
I change the color thanks to myElement.style.color=newColor; but the change disappear as soon as the clock is updated.

How can I make those change permanently ? (without reloading the page)

Thanks for the help !

-- Edit --

Minimal example of the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
    <div class="module-content">
        <div>
            <div class="time">
                18:48:12
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JS code that update the clock is taken from "https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/blob/master/modules/default/clock/clock.js". And I haven't find an easy way to extract a minimal example. Sorry for that.

My code JS that update the style of the clock :

```
function changeColorClass (color, classname) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.color=color;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to choices one is get help from server side or use localStorage for temporary.

Comment: Hi Nakeuh, where's your code? Include it in the post please. Give us a [mcve]